# Migrate .net framework project in IIS to a local project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, iis

I got a web service that lives in IIS currently and for me to edit it I use visual studio on that server and `"Open->Web Site...->"` Then selects the web page and then edit it directly in visual studio.

Now I want to make a copy of it so I can develop on it locally instead of doing it directly on the server. I was able to create a `.sln` file and I got this from it `TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5"`

So I created a project local on my machine with `.net framework 4.5` and just added all the files/folders to that project.

It seems like the classes from that project is all missing namespace though so any kind of reference doesn't work. I also tried to add a namespace to two classes that one is dependent on the other. But it doesn't seem to work and its like 1000 files.

Anyone got any kind of experience with these kind of migrations and can point me to the right direciton?

Comment: A reference could be an installed dll on the server or using other projects.  Start by looking in server bin folder for dll files.   Also you can open the csproj (text file) to look for references that may not be in the main folder.

Comment: The technology you use is the ancient "ASP.NET Web Site" project type offered in .NET Framework early days. Nobody should use it any more, and migrating to at least ASP.NET Web Application project type (if not yet ASP.NET Core) is what you should do now. There isn't a simple migrate path either. You need to create new projects in VS and cut/paste useful code snippets over. If this is too much for you, hire someone with the experience.

Comment: This link should help you: [Convert ASP.NET "Website Project" from IIS to IIS Express](https://timwappat.info/post/2017/01/30/Convert-ASPNET-Website-Project-from-IIS-to-IIS-Express).

Answer (score 0):

You open this website in your local visual studio and press ctrl+shift+s. Then select the file location and save the .sln file. After this, reopen the project with .sln. Now, you can use the NuGet package manager.

You can not just copy because there is a difference between a website and a web application project. Web Application projects have namespace but websites do not.

Comment: I tried creating a .sln on the server but it seems like its referencing the IIS/website so I can't use it locally without modification.

Comment: I have almost 3.5-year experience on website (.Net Framework version 4.0). I think you can do that, there is nothing that depends on IIS. I am converting this type of project.

Comment: I cannot open the website on my local visual studio though as the site is hosted on a server.